# How to find Text in a .txt file and print it out into the console in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help, so I've got an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(part[0], part[1], part[2], part[3], part[4])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The program I'm trying to make is Finding text inside a .txt file and printing it out into my terminal/console in python.
The Python code is:

```
# I = index

file = open("movies.txt", "r")

for line in file:
  part = line.split("/")
  print(part[0], part[1], part[2], part[3], part[4])
  break
file.close()
```

And the .txt file is: (file is called movies.txt)

```
Monsters Inc.,John Goodman,Fantasy,2001,8/10
Toy Story 3,Tom Hanks,Childrens,2010,7/10
The Lego Movie,Chris Pratt,Animated,2014,6/10
Frozen 2,Idina Menzel,Musical,2019,8/10
```

I think I got some index's messed up but I have tried this multiple times and Researched about it yet I can't find help, so I came to stack overflow. Please help me! :)

Comment: Splitting at `/` gives only two values, perhaps you meant to split at `,` (`line.split(",")`)?

Comment: Thanks @MrGeek It works!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer because @MrGeek helped me. What I needed to do was change

```
line.split("/")
```

to

```
line.split(",")
```

I guess A little error like this can get you debugging for a while :/
Thanks @MrGeek!